# Angular how to manage multiple canvas elements for images

Tags: angular, canvas

I have a page with many images. the ngFor worked ok for image tags

But I want canvas(es)

[image]
I do  not know how to manage "id" and getElementById , in a dynamic environment

```
Eg: 
I can update  <canvas id="tools_sketch"  style="border:1px solid #000000;">
to
 <canvas id="tools_sketch{{q}}"  style="border:1px solid #000000;">
```

But how to update

```
const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('tools_sketch??');
```

Please see the stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fk9hbp?file=src/app/app.component.html

How can I locate the element (or ) alternate solution please
(how is image tag working? and not canvas ?)

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to bind to `[id]` attribute.

```
  <div *ngFor="let q of [0, 1]">
    [{{ q }}]
    <img id="myimage" [src]="getImage(q)" />

    <canvas [id]="'tools_sketch_' + q" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
```

using the `q` variable: `[id]="'tools_sketch_' + q"`

Then you can use it TS with something like:

```
  draw() {
    this.drawOnCanvas(0);
    this.drawOnCanvas(1);
  }
  private drawOnCanvas(canvasId: number) {
    const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>(
      document.getElementById('tools_sketch_' + canvasId) // <-- id
    );
    if (!canvas) {
      return;
    }

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(<HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('myimage'), 0, 0);
  }
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6bc5y7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**UPDATE**

To display different images on 1st and 2nd canvas

load images and when all the images are loaded call the draw method:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.imageArray.forEach((q) => {
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + q;
      image.onload = () => {
        console.log('onload');
        ++this.loadedImageCounter;

        if (this.imageArray.length == this.loadedImageCounter) {
          this.draw();
        }
      };
      this.images.push(image);
    });
  }
```

all images are stored in a separate array and a callback `onload` is registered to get notification when an image is ready when all is ready - loaded. then issue a `draw` call. Beside canvasId and imageId is also provided.

```
  draw() {
    console.log('draw');

    this.drawOnCanvas(0, 0);
    this.drawOnCanvas(1, 1);
  }
  private drawOnCanvas(canvasId: number, imageId: number) {
    const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>(
      document.getElementById('tools_sketch_' + canvasId)
    );
    if (!canvas) {
      return;
    }

    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.drawImage(this.images[imageId], 0, 0);
  }
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kn5u62?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I see first image in both the canvas. I'm looking for 2nd image in 2nd canvas

Comment: @KrisSwat sorry my bad, I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks @robert . I see the working. My screen is dynamic with many images., and I currently load images based on rest -> <img id="myimage" [src]='getImage(goal.pic)' />  .  Looks like I have to call this.drawOnCanvas that many times. I will try and then accept the answer